# Is Drupal suitable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a requirement of developing a web applications where users have to maintain a status for a certain entity (like we see in Jira). Can I achieve this with Drupal ?

Actual requirement is to create a workflow like environment.

- A user creates an entity (say an order)
- That entity may consist of text, image, zip files. (uploading required)
- Once created, entity will be updated with a state, say 'created' and another group of users will be able to observe them.
- Users can change the state of the order, like in a work-flow, changing the status from one to another until it reaches the end, say 'completed'.

This is the core requirement & I want to know whether I can manage this kind of a scenario with Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal is a content management system.  Jira is a bug tracking/project tracking system.

Q: Can you create a bug tracking and/or project tracking system in Drupal?  Yes.  But it will require a bit of programming development on your side.

Q: Why not just use Jira?  Or consider an open-source alternative (like Bugzilla)?

Comment: I have edited my question with details. Sorry for being stupid :)

Comment: OK: then I think your best bet might be to Google for "open source project management".  For example: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/open-source-project-management-software.html

Answer (score 0):

There are actually a number of project management and ticket tracking options in drupal. Most exist for D6, but [Case Tracker](http://drupal.org/project/casetracker) is being ported to D7.

Perhaps you might be able to begin your build with existing contributed code.